# MacOS Cocoa, why am i not able to close windows?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

i am working in XCode Swift, with Cocoa with Storyboards, and i need to be able to create and close my own windows, programmatically.

to repeat the problem as simply as possible, i start with an empty storyboard project, and change only viewDidLoad in ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let rect = NSRect( x:500, y:500, width:800, height:500 )
    let mask = NSWindow.StyleMask( arrayLiteral: .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .titled )
    let win = NSWindow( contentRect: rect, styleMask: mask, backing: .buffered, defer: false )
    
    win.orderFront( win )
}
```

the application runs, and puts up two windows.  the smaller one is from the storyboard and can be closed without trouble, but when i close the larger window which i created, the application crashes in the appDelegate with

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

i assume i am doing something dumb here - what am i missing?

i discovered if i set

win.isReleasedWhenClosed = false

the problem goes away, however i assume the memory is not being released.

i also found that if i append the window handle to an array before closing it, the problem also goes away:

```
private var broken_windows [NSWindow] = []

public func windowShouldClose( _ sender: NSWindow ) -> Bool {
    
    broken_windows.append( sender )
    return true
}
```

however this array is somehow completely untouchable, and any attempt to access it's members after the window has been closed will cause the application to crash.

Comment: Where in the app delegate is the crash happening? You haven't shown your app delegate code.

Comment: i have no app delegate code, this is an empty project, as described, modified only by the code i posted in the question.  i expect that there is something i must implement in the app delegate to close the windows properly, and i do not know what code to put here - that is my question.

Comment: when i say "i have no app delegate code" i mean that i have not modified the default template provided by the Xcode IDE when i started the project.  i would post that here, but i assume not appropriate in a comment.  i do not mean there is no app delegate.  when the app crashes, lldb points to the `class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {` declaration, and gives me a stack trace that i cannot follow.

Answer (score 0):

In your updated code, the window is only retained because you are holding a [strong reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID49) to it via `self.win`. If you use `weak var win: NSWindow?`, then `self.win` will be nil after the window is closed. So, setting `isReleasedWhenClosed = false` does seem to be a valid solution.

Comment: please see my initial question - setting `isReleasedWhenClosed = false` only serves to prevent the app from crashing, but it leaves the window hanging in memory.  if i hold a strong reference to the window, then the app will not crash in the delegate, as described, but it will crash as soon as i delete the reference.  using a weak reference has no effect, the app still crashes when the window is closed.

Comment: That's not true – I created a sample project and pasted your code, added `win.isReleasedWhenClosed = false`, and the app does not crash when both windows are closed, even without any references in an instance variable or array. I am running macOS 12.1.

Comment: Maybe in your actual non-sample project you have something else holding a strong reference to the window?